# how to make a margin white

Tags: html, css

Can somebody help me to make these marked margins white.
I have this code:

```
   #div3 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #464646;
    color: white;
    height: 300px;
}

h1 {
    margin-left: 280px;
    font-size: 40px;
}

p {
    margin-left: 280px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#a2 {
    color: orangered;
    margin-left:470;
}
#div4 {
    background-color: white;
}
```

HTML part:

```
<div id="div4">
      <div id="div3">
        <img src="img1.jpg" width="630px" height="300px" style=" float:right; margin-right: 160px;">
          <div>
          <h1>Eu justo ague estas</h1>
            <p> A dream is a succession of images, ideas, emotions, and sensations that usually occur involuntarily in the mind during certain stages of sleep.</p> 
              <a href="https://www.google.com/" id="a2"> Read more </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

changing margin into padding does not work.
[image]

Parent div #div4 seems not to work

Answer (score 0):

You cant color margins. But what you can do is to make a parent div and make the background white. Then make the childs background grey.

```css
#div3 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #464646;
    margin: 0 280px;
    color: white;
    height: 300px;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  #a2 {
    color: orangered;
    margin-left: 470;
  }
  #div4 {
    background-color: white;
  }
```

Comment: Mark his post as answer if it fixed it

Comment: Maybe you could add a code snippet with an at least somewhat similar setup to illustrate better what you meant? But @JosanVeronica, it's basically that. Margins can't be colored in CSS because they're not elements, they're just space. So you have to put something behind to hold that color.

Comment: If I had the html though. Without that what can I post as code?

Comment: I edited the question  and added html part

Comment: Here you go. I hope this helps. And try to give the parent margin instead of childrens one by one.

Answer (score 0):

@Amin Darian's answer is pretty cut and dried.

Have you tried something like:

```
#div4 {
    background-color: white;
    padding-left: 160px;
    padding-right: 160px;
}
```

?

If it works, you can accept Amin's answer.

EDIT:

You also might not need all those divs depending on the rest of your code. Here's a simplified starting point:

```
<html>
<body style="background-color: white;">
     <div id="darkDiv" style="margin-left: 180px; margin-right: 180px; background-color: #464646; color: white;">
          <img src="img1.jpg" width="630px" height="300px" style=" float: right;">
          <div id="textDiv">
              Your h1 and link with styling
          </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```